# How to limit number of Linux processes spawned per minute?

Tags: python, linux, process, fork, spawn

My application requires to inhibit any fork bombs created by Python/Bash. I use *ulimit* program which set a limit to number of processes per user.

Can anyone suggest me how I could limit number of processes *per minute* instead of per user ?

Comment: The only idea I have is to replace the original binaries of `bash` and `python` by wrappers which count along and perform delays if necessary before starting the original binaries.  Does that sound suitable in your environment?  But anyway, it would only work against `exec`s, not against pure `fork` bombs.  You would have to patch your kernel to achieve that goal.  Maybe there is a kind of security kernel enhancement which can do that for you already.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default way to set number of process per minute. As you said ulimit will be only for per user. Instead you can do a work around as below,

```
   ps -aux |wc -l
```

This will give you the number of process running currently. write a script which will continuously check for every one minute and update you the result .